# Retrieve File name from SpooledTemporaryFile in python

Tags: python

I am receiveing a binary data in a field like this

```
<FileStorage: u'SampleDoc.docx' ('application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document')>
```

I need to retrieve the file name and store it in another variable.

How can i do this?

Comment: Is the given line is string?

Comment: Note that `SpooledTemporaryFile` might not generate a file at all, since it can store data on memory as long as it fits. Thus, the idea of getting a filename from such context manager is, at least weird. You may want to take a look at `NamedTemporaryFile`. For further details you can read the documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html

Comment: You might be able to get a file name by `tempFile.name`. But as pointed out, it could be `None`.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the docs (https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html). The `SpooledTemporaryFile` might not create a file on your HDD at all. The data you write to the file-like object it returns may just be kept in memory.
For that reason you are likely interested in `NamedTemporaryFile` so that you can do something like:

```py
with NamedTemporaryFile() as fileout:
    ...
    filename = fileout.name
```

Note that if you need to access it and you use the context manager, you'll have to place your file reading code within the context, as the file won't exist outside of it.